# Shorthand for Interlocked.Exchange in property setter

Tags: .net, vb.net, decompiling, decompiler, shorthand

I have the following simple piece of variable declaration a class with generated by a decompiler

```
Friend Class Project
    Private _Status As Integer
    Public Property Status As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._Status
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Interlocked.Exchange(Me._Status, value)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Is there is any shorthand form for this declaration.
Actually this is used internally backgroundworker inside the class and accessed externally by another classes.

To be clear in what is the meaning of shorthand. I will give an example:
The following gode is a shorthand

```
SyncLock lock
    z = 1
End SyncLock
```

for the following detailed code

```
Dim obj As Object = Me.lock
ObjectFlowControl.CheckForSyncLockOnValueType(obj)
Dim flag As Boolean = False
Try
    Monitor.Enter(obj, flag)
    Me.z = 1
Finally
    If (flag) Then
        Monitor.[Exit](obj)
    End If
End Try
```

Answer (score 4):

As Holterman has mentioned, the only benefit that the `Interlocked.Exchange` provides is the memory barrier. (`Int32` assignments are always atomic in .NET, and you're discarding the return value.)

If the source code had been written in C#, it is possible that it originally contained the `volatile` keyword, which also generates memory barriers.

```
private volatile int _Status;
public int Status
{
    get { return _Status; }
    set { _Status = value; }
}
```

However, this should have resulted in a memory barrier being generated in the getter as well.

Answer (score 3):

> `Interlocked.Exchange(Me._Status, value)`

1. It's already a one-liner, how much shorter do you think it can get?
2. The only benefit from using Exchange(Int32) is the memory barrier it causes. So when you like it better, you can replace it by your sample `SyncLock` for the same effect.

Comment: But SyncLock decompiles to different syntax as mentioned in the question.

Comment: So, decompilers make choices.